# Servlet syntax for obtaining parameter values

Tags: jsp, servlets

Whats the servlet syntax to obtain parameter value that comes after the question mark in jsp page for processing in servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JSP you need to use expression language. For parameters, it looks like `${param['mycom.productId']}` . Check out [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) for more details

Answer (score -1):

Look at the [javadoc for HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) (and its parent interface), and especially the methods containing the word "Parameter".

Answer (score -1):

The HttpServletRequest has a getParameter method.  An example getting the parameter "name" is shown below where req is the HttpServletRequest.  I also advise reading the documents in @JB Nizet's answer.

```
String name = req.getParameter("name"));
```

Comment: How to pass the (String name = req.getParameter("name");) in jsp page to the servlet for processing without using the session.
Note: servlet is called by form action in jsp

Comment: You need to submit the parameter value as a form input (text input, or hidden input, for example)

Comment: thanks a lot...i may try to pass it as hidden input

Comment: @MathanaPrithiviraj I think you are misunderstanding what you need to do.  The backend Java servlet would contain the code in my answer.  It would not need to be placed in the jsp page itself.  Only the input field would need to be place with a name attribute of what you want to call the parameter.  For example, `<input type="text" name="name" />` would result in the form submitting the input placed in the text box as the parameter "name" to the backend Java servlet processing the Http request.

Comment: hi...Lipongo....I may state my problem very claerly....

i have 3 jsp forms in three separate jsp pages...
1)view form
2)add form
3)edit form..

In view form the database values are designed in tables...and each row has href to edit page and the row id is passed in url parameter to edit page from view page....

My question is how to pass the row id value in edit page form url to the servlet.....(Servlet is called by edit form action... )